# bootstrap-datepicker double addon and stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker, stoppropagation

I use bootstrap-datepicker and want to have a second addon with a checkbox.
I don't want trigger the show of datepicker when i click in the checkbox addon.
I tested the stopPropagation, return false on the onclick event of the second addon but it doesn't work :(

```
<div class="container"> 
 <div class ="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Received Date</label>        
<div class="col-sm-2 input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" id="ARDT">
  <input class="text-input form-control" type="text" name="ARDT"  maxlength="10" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>                                           
  <span class="input-group-addon test"><input type="checkbox"/></span>
</div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

with this javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ARDT').datepicker();    
$('.date .test').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

you can view live on this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5a5xzz10/4/

Can you help me ?

Thanks
Whiletrue

EDIT : Found a solution :

```
  <div class ="form-group">
<label class="control-label" >Received Date OK</label>      
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" id="ARDT2">
    <input class="text-input form-control" type="text" name="ARDT"  maxlength="10" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>                                         
  </div>
  <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox"/></span>
</div>
</div>
```

embbed the input-group for the datepicker inside another and put the second input-group-addon just after

like here : http://jsfiddle.net/5a5xzz10/6

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer but it doesn't seems very elegant.

I added the checkbox after started the datepicker generation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ARDT').datepicker();
    $("div.date").append($('<span class="input-group-addon test"><input type="checkbox"/></span>'));
});
```

Comment: This workaround doen't work, cause the datepicker set all the input value in the component include the checkbox... i found another workaround, embed the input-group inside another like here : http://jsfiddle.net/5a5xzz10/6/